# Using random.choice on items which might be locked by threading.Lock

Tags: python, multithreading, random

I am developing a search tree agent which is able to use multi threads to grow its nodes.
every node has these features:

```
import threading
def __init__(self, move=None, parent=None):    
  self.lock = threading.Lock()
  self.lock.acquire()
  self.move = move
  self.parent = parent
  self.N = 0  
  self.Q = 0
  self.children = {}
  self.lock.release()
```

As you can see whenever a node is initialized, it is locked to avoid possible duplicates of node.
In some place of my code I put all the nodes of a parent node in a list and select randomly:

```
max_nodes = [n for n in node.children.values()]
node = random.choice(max_nodes)
```

If during the creation of max_nodes list, a node was locked (nodes could be locked from time to time), what would happen to the random selection.
does it wait for all the nodes to be released or not?
I ask the question because I get this error multiple times:
`cannot choose from an empty list`

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how the Lock type works. If you access the "children" instance variable directly, then the Lock isn't involved at all. The most likely reason for your error is that the "children" dict is simply empty.

Comment: It's wrong to instantiate the `Lock` in the same Function you are using it. You have to do it in the `__main__` Thread.

Comment: I just wanted to know does random function wait for all the nodes to be released or not? the main program is too large and I can not put it here.